# Trouble populating selectlist in controller code - C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I have a fairly straight forward requirement - to populate a viewmodel, which has a SelectList as one of its properties - NewOccs is defined on the model as:

```
   public class RatesList
   {
    [Key]
    public long TypeID { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public int TypeCount { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> NewOccs { get; set; }
   }
```

My controller code to populate it is:

```
   var rooms = dbt.Rooms.Where(r => r.hotel_id == AccID)
               .GroupBy(p => p.RoomTypes).Select(g => new RatesList
                {
                    TypeName = g.Key.type_name,
                    TypeCount = g.Count(),
                    NewOccs = dbt.Rates.Where(rt => rt.type_id == g.Key.type_id).GroupBy(rt => rt.occ).AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(proj => new SelectListItem
                       {
                           Text = proj.Key,
                           Value =proj.Key
                       })

                }).ToList();
```

The Rates table it should be getting its information from is:

```
public class Rates
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public long type_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ratedate { get; set; }
    public decimal rate { get; set; }
    public string occ { get; set; }
}
```

How to I access any of the other fields in my Rates table - when I'm populating the SelectList?  For example, in VSExpressIDE intellisense only allows me to type `proj.Key` - the other properties are not there.  I want `occ` to be the key/value and I would like the text to be a concatenation of `occ` and `rate` - ie:

```
Text = proj.occ + ' ' + rate.ToString()
```

...but `rate` and `occ` cannot be found in intellisense.

Thank you, Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you step through your debugger, you'll see that `GroupBy()` provides a `GroupedEnumerable`, which contains Keys.  The keys are `Lookup<string, Rates>`, because you used GroupBy on a string.

If you changed your Select to a SelectMany, you'd see all your Rates.  But that would defeat the purpose of the GroupBy.  I'm not totally sure what you want in the end, but [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35667/How-to-Use-LINQ-GroupBy-2) is a good guide to GroupBy

Answer (score 1):

Like  this:

```
public class Client
{
    public int SelectedSexId { get; set; }
    public IList<Sex> SexList { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> SexListSelectListItems
    {
        get
        {
            SexList=SexList??new List<Sex>();
            var list = (from item in SexList
                        select new SelectListItem()
                        {
                            Text = item.Name,
                            Value = item.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        }).ToList();
            return list;
        }
        set { }
    }
}
```